# Data Flow Partition by Column Value Not Writing Unique Column Values to Each Folder

Tags: azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-data-factory, expressionbuilder

I am reading an SQL DB as source and it outputs the following table.

[image]

My intention is to use data flow to save each unique type into a data lake folder partition probably named as specific type.

I somehow manage to create individual folders but my data flow saves the entire table with all types into each of the folders.

my data flow

[image]

Source

[image]

Window

[image]

[image]

Sink
[image]

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the output you expect? How did you set the windows sort/ windows columns? Did you check the sink output data preview?

Comment: I think you need a Aggregate active get you want.

Comment: @Leon Yue Invited you on chat because of the sensitivity of info

Comment: Hi @wwnde, I'm in the chatting room

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230297/room-for-wwnde-and-leon-yue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a same csv source and it works well, please ref my example.

Windows settings:
[image]
[image]

Sink settings: choose the file name option like this
[image]

Note, please don't set optmize again in sink side.

The output folder schema we can get:

[image]

Just for now, Data Factory Data Flow doesn't support custom the output file name.

HTH.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try "Name folder as column data" using the OpType column instead of using partitioning. This is a property in the Sink settings.

[image]